# What programming language is displayed?

Tags: compiler-construction, ssa

Since I couldn't find anything on Google and I have never seen such syntax before

```
t11 = phi [0: 2:int, 1: t10] #i
t12 = t11 < 70:int
if t12 goto 1 else 2
t2 = t11 / 2:int
t3 = &pow10tab[t11]
t4 = &pow10tab[t2]
t5 = *t4
t6 = t11 - t2
```

I like to ask what programming language is displayed?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide more information where this snippet is coming from? I.e. if it is from a file, the file name and extension. If it is part of package or directory the name of that?

Comment: this code comes from a text file which is a part of a question(sort of a challenge) needs to be solved.
The name of the file is simply f67890.txt.

There are a lot of lines like those lines: (the file contains about 185k lines)

Starting math.hasSSE4 at /usr/lib/go-1.7/src/math/floor_asm.go:10:6.
 (external)
Returning from math.hasSSE4, proceeding math.init at /usr/lib/go-1.7/src/math/floor_asm.go:12:22.
  *useSSE4 = t1
  t2 = &_gamP[0:int]
  t3 = &_gamP[1:int]

Comment: Is the file is from 10th International Conference on Computer Science and its Applications (CSA 2018)?
 ... 35.194.63.219/csa_2018/trace_me_if_you_can/f67890.txt). Speaks anything against the [SSA representation of the intermediate stages of the Go compiler](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/ssa-to-go-decompiler/9223)?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It is not a programming language.</strike> as per @[Ira Baxter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120163/ira-baxter)s comment. It is the [static single assignment form (SSA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form)

> *In compiler design, static single assignment form (often abbreviated as SSA form or simply SSA) is a property of an intermediate representation (IR), which requires that each variable is assigned exactly once, and every variable is defined before it is used.*

If interested in more background information, you may have a look into the Golang, compiler backend and SSA documentation or compiler building in general.

Comment: (The hint this is SSA is the "phi" operator) .SSA basically *is* a programming language; after all, one can write programs in it.    Just not one used by most programmers; rather it is used as the internals of a compiler to represent an equivalent of the original program which is easier to reason about and manipulate.

Comment: I see, it is an Intermediate Language (IL). From Wikipedia I've learned *"The phi function (φ function) is a construct in compiler construction.

In the internal representation of program code in SSA representation, each variable is written only once. Since different variables are written in alternative branches, after the unification of the control flow (for example, after an if / then / else), the problem that later code can access only one variable must be solved.

This is solved by the phi function, which returns its parameters as a result of the actually taken control flow."*

Comment: Thank you ver much, you helped me a lot